# how to display selected values in crystal report using Asp.Net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2008

i had employee details table and minimum 40 fields i have to asp.net. want take report in crystal report. each and every fields have check box if i select some check box that fields only want display in crystal report

so anyone can help me solve this problem and sorry for my English

Comment: Check http://dotnetmentors.com/reporting/crystal-report-with-stored-procedure-parameter-and-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: i use multiple check box so whatever i select to check box means that fields only want to display other fields don't want

Answer (score 0):

you Can control Report data source 
as example

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell ch1 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
                    ch1 = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells["Check"];
                      if (ch1.Value !=null )
                    {
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                    }
                }
```

Or you can suppress Row in Crystal report Which Check=false